# Running Java process in Azure

Tags: java, asp.net, azure

I have an asp.net app that will eventually be deployed on Azure. At some point, the app runs a Java process, somewhat like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process clientProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
clientProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
clientProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
clientProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar GCC/compiler.jar --js GCC/JSTest/hello.js --js_output_file GCC/JSTest/hello-compiled.js";
clientProcess.Start();
clientProcess.WaitForExit();
```

I have included the `java.exe` file and the `compiler.jar` file in the directories of the app and everything works. My question is this: will this code also work in Azure as-is or do I need to make some modifications?

Comment: Don't you need to deploy the core Java Class Libraries as well?

Comment: you probably need to make sure the JDK/JRE is install on the instance (and java.exe is in the PATH)